# Full POST body not being delivered

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express to interact with an IoT device. The device interacts correctly with a Django server I wrote, but not with the node.js server I'm writing now. It appears that device writes a first packet with the HTTP headers (including "Content-Length") and the final "\r\n\r\n", and then a second packet with the POST body. Express is calling my post handler with no body.

Like I said, Django handles this correctly. I THINK what is being done is legal HTTP/TCP and Express is not waiting for the full length of the "Content-Length" header when it should. Is this a part of Express' design? Can I turn it off so that it waits for the whole document? Is this a bug and I should use a different framework with this device?

Comment: try `req.pipe(process.stdout)` I suspect express is working as intended, by not waiting on the body before calling your handler, which is not the bahavior you want, you can fix it by adding body parsing middleware (I'm assuming you're using the latest express)

Comment: I'll check that out.

Comment: Adding the line the @generalhenry suggested to my post handler did output the full body to standard out, although it did it after the post body was processed as it is asynchronously. If you would like to write up a full solution on how to create structure the middleware, I'll accept that solution, otherwise I'll come back with what I make later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The express framework is unique among http frameworks in that it gets smaller each release.  One of the parts that was removed from the core is body parsing, so it now handles request bodies as base node.js does unless you add middleware.

In a standard post handler the request object is a stream containing the headers which allows you to react to the request before the request has even finished sending data.

It's easiest to see with an echo handler:

```
echo (req, res) {
  req.pipe(res);
}
```

But most the time you want to process the post body as a whole

```
postBody (req, res) {
  let body = '';
  req.on('data', d => body += d.toString()); // it comes in as a buffer
  req.on('error', e => { res.statusCode = 400; res.end('bad post data'); });
  req.on('end', () => /*do something with the body */ res.end(body));
}
```

Which means the minimal middleware simply calls next after assigning the body to req.body.  Though in practice you should use https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser or the like since it handles edge cases etc . . .

```
bodyMiddleware (req, res, next) {
  let body = '';
  req.on('data', d => body += d.toString()); // it comes in as a buffer
  req.on('error', e => { res.statusCode = 400; res.end('bad post data'); });
  req.on('end', () => { req.body = body; next(); });
}
```

Comment: I'm giving credit, because this worked for me when I did this in the POST handler inside a Promise (though it didn't work for me when I tried to do it in middleware; the stream events didn't fire). However, it ended up pointing me in the direction of my real problem. Here's the context I didn't know I didn't include: I had the JSON body parser from body-parser included and was using it. However, the embedded device wasn't including Content-Type, so all of the available body parsers were being skipped. As @generalhenry said in the final paragraph, the body parsers should handle this.